# When do we get a "subjective question" warning?

Tags: discussion, site-general, questions

While writing this [question about range counting](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/1135/whats-the-best-way-to-count-numbers-in-a-set-that-are-below-a-given-threshold) I was warned by the site that it is likely subjective and will be closed.

1. Do you think it is subjective?

2.1. If yes, then why?

2.2. If no, then why did I get the (automated) warning?

Comment: See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20010/what-algorithm-does-stackoverflow-use-to-determine-if-a-question-may-be-subjectiv

Comment: that matching algorithm is actually silly. the question was perfectly reasonable even though it used the word 'best'.

Comment: Thanks. I decided to delete the question. It was a bad question after all: (1) to find what is known about "range counting" I can search for papers, (2) the more general setting I described allowed solutions (like the sorted array) that are not obviously useful when talking about red-black trees (and that was supposed to be the motivation).